# Applying Two Different Materials on 2 Sides of a Face

Tags: materials, faces

I have to apply two different materials on the two different sides of a face. I know how to use double sided materials (with two different pricipled bsdf shaders and a geometry node connected to a mix node), but in this case I will have a single material behaving differently on the 2 sides. I need 2 different materials on the two sides of the face to import the model in substance painter.

Is there any chance to apply the two different materials on the two sides or the only chance is to produce a double sided single material?

Comment: No, every face has exactly one material. Can you use two faces right on top of each other instead?

Comment: Use two different UV maps and assign the material coordinates so that each material is mapped with a unique UV map